# Set ItemStyle for dataset.source in ECharts to individually colour datapoints on line graph

Tags: javascript, visualization, echarts

I am want to set the colour of each symbol in Echarts individually while using the `dataset.source` way of displaying data.

Minimial repro is here: https://codepen.io/isachenx/pen/BaEooWx

I forked the "[Distribution of Electricity" example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-sections). Instead of using series.data for x and y axis separately, I used `dataset.source` and added the itemStyle to the datapoint. I am trying to change the red point at index 8 to green so that the circles are always green even if line is red.

I would like to achieve this effect where the red line is "capped" with a green symbol. It's documented how to do with series-line.data.itemStyle.color: https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-line.data.itemStyle.
But I want to do it with `dataset.source`

[image]
This works:

```
series: [
   data:[
     100, 
     200,
     {
       value:300,
       itemStyle: {color: "green"}
     }
   ]
]
```

But not possible it seems when using:

```
dataset: 
  { 
    source: [
     100, 
     200,
     {
       value:300,
       itemStyle: {color: "green"}
     }
    ]
  }
```